# Budget of religions

Tags: finance, religion

I want to see how religions receive and spend their money.

Example:

```
ReligionA:
  Income:
    50% donations
    30% rents
    10% subsidies
    10% graveyard fees
  Expenditure:
    40% humanitarian donations
    30% salaries
    20% buildings maintenance
    10% others
ReligionB:
  [...]
```

- By "religion" I actually mean "religious organization", with local religious leaders at the bottom and a chain of responsibility leading to a central authority.
- Religions without an organization are out of scope.
- The income/spending patterns of a religious organization's Luxemburg branch and Ethiopia branch are probably different, these should be summed up to present a global view.
- Due to [complex](http://www.slate.com/articles/business/moneybox/2013/03/catholic_church_and_pope_francis_religious_institutions_are_exempted_from.html) [structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Islamic_muftiates) this is probably very difficult to calculate, so estimation-based data is fine.
- I am mostly interested in percentages, but actual amounts would be even better.

Comment: I suspect the last sector that "open data" reaches will be religious orgs.